# How to setup PyCharm to use virtualenv in Vagrant/VirtualBox remote interpreter configuration?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, virtualhost, pycharm

PyCharm running under Windows.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS VM hosted under VirtualBox.

Setting up PyCharm to use Vagrant to launch said VM and use the remote Python interpreter works as advertised.  However, this also happens to be the interpreter and packages used by Ubuntu.

How would one modify this setup to use one or more virtualenvs on the VM?  The idea being that each project could very well have radically different requirements and they should be isolated from each other and the system through virtualenv.

Would this require using Apache VirtualHost to setup separate projects?  Any docs on doing that for Python and/or Python/Django projects?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

We are using vagrant and we have more than 100 sites with different virtual environments. I set up the projects within /vagrant/projects folder which is a shared folder between the host and guest. This way we can work on the projects from within vagrant guest machine or from an ide within the host machine depending on the preference of the developer.

Every project has its own apache virtualhost conf and the virtual environments are located in /usr/local/virtualenvs/. For example:

/vagrant/projects/site1 with virtual environment /usr/local/virtualenvs/site1 and so on.

The apache conf for one site looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin your@email.com
   ServerName site1

   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_site1.log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_site1.log common

   WSGIDaemonProcess site1 user=www-data group=www-data umask=0002 threads=3 python-path=/vagrant/projects/site1/web/site1:/usr/local/virtualenvs/site1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
   WSGIProcessGroup site1
   WSGIScriptAlias / /vagrant/projects/site1/web/server.wsgi
   <Directory />
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks none ExecCGI
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       ServerSignature Off
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You can also use vagrant-hostmanager plugin to automatically edit the hosts file withing your host and guest machines. So you can directly access your domains without having to edit the hosts files manually all the time.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken this says what to do, but not how to do it?  As per the question I was looking for instructions on how to get PyCharm to use a virtualenv within Vagrant...

Comment: you can share the virtual hosts folder with the guest and go from there maybe? My answer is mostly related to the last questions asked within the text, maybe not the question in the title.

Answer (score 7):

I found the accepted answer helpful, but in line with @miR's comment...

To set PyCharm to use the virtual environment, you can edit/set the Python interpreter path to the virtualenv's binary.
E.g. my virtualenv (created in Ubuntu Vagrant VM via ssh) was `/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/project/bin/python3` so I just copied that path into the "Python Interpreter Path" field in "Project Interpreter".

That worked nicely. I can even use the PyCharm interface to install packages into the virtualenv on the Vagrant VM.

Comment: Good tip! I'm doing this with a Django app inside Vagrant running with a Virtual Environment and the only other step I needed to use PyCharm's Django runners was to deselect both "Add content roots to PYTHONPATH" and "Add source roots to PYTHONPATH" and just putting the remove working directory path in for "working directory. 

Might not be the best combination, but it's working now.